# GXT - How can I add the Grid Filter parameters to the Request URL (get parameters)?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

GXT - How can I add the Grid Filter parameters to the Request URL (get parameters)?

```
final PagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy, reader) {  
  @Override  
  protected Object newLoadConfig() {  
    BasePagingLoadConfig config = new BaseFilterPagingLoadConfig();  
    return config;  
  }  
};
```

=

Request URL:http://localhost/index.php?action=getLines&limit=10&sortField=null&offset=0&sortDir=NONE&filters=[com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseStringFilterConfig@3abbafc7]

filters=[com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseStringFilterConfig@3abbafc7] ???

How can convert this line for a request url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a toString method is missing in the BaseStringFilterConfig in order to use it as you describe.

Make sure you use a *BaseStringFilterConfig* that defines the toString method - to do so, you'd have to overwrite it manually.

Create a class that extends the *BaseStringFilterConfig* class and overrides the toString() method.

As an example you could use a 
    private static final class BaseStringFilterConfigWithStringRepresentation extends BaseStringFilterConfig {

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[field=" + getField() + "| comparison=" + 
                    getComparison() + " | type=" + getType() + " | value=" +
                    getValue() + "]";
    }

}
```

Be careful not to use a comma as a delimiter, as the *filters* field already comes as a comma delimited list. You'd have to parse it on the server-side somehow and then return correct result.

Answer (score 0):

in HttpProxy
there is this method

```
  protected String generateUrl(C loadConfig) {
    if (writer != null) {
      return writer.write(loadConfig);
    } else {
      if (loadConfig == null) {
        return "";
      }
      return loadConfig.toString();
    }
  }
```

So, if you have defined a DataWriter for your HttpProxy with the method
setWriter it will be used, if not the toString method is used.
There is a DataWriter - UrlEncodingWriter which I believe you need here